# We are given a number lets say m. We have to distribute the number into n parts

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Lets says I have a number `m = 9`. I want to divide it into `n=5` parts like given below:

As `m>n`, each part will get at least `1`.

First give `1` to all `5` `parts`

`part0`: 1,
`part1`: 1,
`part2`: 1,
`part3`: 1,
`part4`: 1

Now for the remaining (`9 - 5 = 4`) divide again starting from 1st. final allocation looks like:

`part0`: 2 
`part1`: 2
`part2`: 2
`part3`: 2
`part4`: 1

algo:
take an array `arr[n]={0}`.

```
x=0
while(m) {
   arr[x]+=1;
   m--;
   x=(x+1)%n;
}
```

My question is I don't want to run this loop to divide n into m parts. Mathematically, how can I know the value allocated to a part directly. i.e  part0: 2 for above example.

Comment: The answer is already in your question: `%`.

Comment: Use modulo to find the remainder '%'

Comment: Generally instead of editing the answer into your question, you should accept one of the answers below (click the check mark next to it) or post your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Integer division gets you the "base" size of all parts: `9 / 5 == 1`.

Modulo gives you the remainder, `9 % 5 == 4`. This means you should add 1 to the first `4` parts.

```
int partCount = 5;
int number = 9;

int base = number / partCount;
int remain = number % partCount;

for (int i=0; i<partCount; i++) {
    part[i] = base;
    if (i < remain) part[i]++;
}
```

The algorithm might be clearer if you use larger numbers. E.g. 31 in 7 parts:

`31 / 7 == 4` - so we have 7 parts of 4 each, (== 28) plus the remainder:
`31 % 7 == 3` - give the first 3 parts 1 more each to make 31 total.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
  arr[i] = m/n + (m%n < i ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: Some explanation how this code works would be great.

Comment: Agree. But another answer is same logic with explanation. I don't see much value in 2 answers stating same thing. What is preferred? To enrich answer, delete it, or something else?